# application migrating from weblogic 9.2 to weblogic 12c

Tags: java-ee-6, weblogic12c, weblogic9.x, migrating

I want to migrate an application from webLogic 9.2 server to webLogic 12 c. I'm newer for this process. Can someone help me for making this, please?
I don't know very much weblogic server.

Thks,

Awa

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of install the binaries and create a new weblogic domain or upgrade the older domain.

if you are using third party jars with your application, you need to tell weblogic to use your application jars instead of its own jars.

This is done in weblogic.xml file. In older versions of weblogic. this tag is used

```
   <prefer-web-inf-classes> true </prefer-web-inf-classes>
```

in weblogic 12c this is not the recommended way. You need to user

```
 <prefer-application-packages> tag and specify the list of application packages that you want to be loaded from your application as opposed to weblogic12c own jars
```

more on this http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/programming/classloading.html

its not a very straight-forward thing to do, so good luck!

Comment: Hi ssayyed,

Thank you for your response. In weblogic.xml file, there's no <prefer-web-inf-classes> tag inside <container-descriptor> tag, because I have no classes in  so the value inside is false by default.

I want to know if there is other things to change or to add in this file, please?

Thanks,

Awa

Comment: Not really, other things that you might want to consider, is that if you upgrade java version (point weblogic to newer JDK installation) in the setDomainEnv script. then you need to build your application's artifacts with the same version. if you haven't tried so already, I say deploy the application in 12c and see what you get, it might just run normally.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I have another question. I began to plan upgrading to WebLogic 12c. But I don't find the directory containing webLogic12c server classes? Have you an idea about it, please?

Comment: The jar files are in wlserver/lib. it has all the weblogic jar files. Unless you specifically mean weblogic.jar. then its different in the weblogic12c as it only contains a Manifest.mf files that points to other jars. Instead of having the classes themselves